# Does tesseract OCR for .net works with pdf files?

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr, tesseract

I want to perform OCR on png and pdf files.I am able to get Tesseract 3.0.2 .net wrapper work for png files but I can't find any class in it for PDf files.So, does it work for the pdf files.If not then please let me know any other open source library for scanning pdfs. My requirement is scanning diagrams in a pdf for specific circles, and creating hyperlinks for those circles.

Comment: You can convert those pdf files to image, then using Tesseract. There are some commercial libraries like Nuance which can handle pdf files; but the price is quite high.

Comment: You can convert the pdfs to pngs for free with ghostscript. I'll be at my desk in a few hours so I can share my implementation. I found it from another SO post.

Comment: did you tried  PDFBox for pdf parsing ? free PDFBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You'll have to extract the images from the pdf first. This can be done using [pdfimages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages) `pdfimages.exe -j your.pdf` or gs as suggested by Zakk Diaz.